# finding whether a path of a specific length exists in an acyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, directed-acyclic-graphs, longest-path

In an acyclic graph, I am trying to find out whether or not a path of length L exists between two given nodes. My questions is, what is the best and the simplest Algorithm to use in this case.

Note that the graph has a maximum of 50 nodes and 100 edges.

I have tried to find all the paths using DFS and then to check if that path exists between the two nodes but I got the answer "Time Limit Exceeded" from the online judge.

I also used the Uniform Cost Search Algorithm but I also a got a negative response.

I need a more efficient way for solving such problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it will be faster then a DFS approach - but it will give a feasible solution:

Represent the graph as a matrix `A`, and calculate **`A^L`** - a path of length L between i and j exists if and only if `A[i][j] != 0`

Also, regarding DFS solution: You do not need to find *all paths* in the DFS - you should **limit yourself to paths of length <= L**, and by this trim some searches, once the length have exceeded the needed length. You could also escape the search once a path of length L is reaching the target.

Another possible optimization could be [**bi-directional search**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search).

- Find all vertices which have path of length L/2 from the source to
  them.
- Next, find all vertices which have paths of length L/2 from them
  to the target (DFS on the reverse graph)
- Then, check if there is a vertex that is common to both sets, if
  there is - you got a path of length L from the source to the target.

Answer (score 2):

Since the graph is acyclic you can order vertices topologicaly.
Let's name starting vertex A and finish vertex B.

Now the core algorithm starts:
For each vertex count all possible distances from A to this vertex. At start there is
one path from A to A with length zero.
Then take vertices in topological order. 
When you pick vertex x: Look at each predecessor and update possible distances here.

This should run in O(N^3) time.

Comment: the starting and the ending nodes are specified in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modified Dijkstra algorithm where instead of saving for every vertex the minimum distance to the origin, you save all the possible distances less or equal to the one desired.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that you can use the following algorithm to find the longest path in a tree.  This assumes that your graph is connected, if it is not you would need to rerun this on each connected component:

1. Pick an arbitrary node, A.
2. Do a BFS (or DFS) from A to find the node in the tree farthest from A, call this node B.
3. Do a BFS (or DFS) from B to find the node in the tree farthest from B, call this node C.
4. The path from B to C is the longest path in the tree (possibly tied for longest).

Obviously if this path is longer than L then you can shorten it to find a path of length L.

Comment: According to your algorithm, if you can go from B to another node, then why did we stop at B in step 2? 
aren't we suppose to keep going to the farthest one?
What's your definition of "a node being the farthest" ?
What's the name of the algorithm you are suggesting here?

Comment: We stop at B because we have to, it's a leaf node and there is no where else to go.  Then we do a different search starting from B, we'll reach A, but then we'll go further and get to C.

A node X is furthest from node Y if there is no node Z such that the distance from X to Z is greater than X to Y.

Comment: I don't know if this algorithm has a name - I came up with it back when I was in school.  I had to prove it at the time, but I remember the proof being a bit tedious so I didn't want to try to redo it here.

Comment: A don't think the question is about trees.

Comment: @usamec - Well it's about acyclic graphs, and acyclic graphs are trees.

Comment: @RunningWild - directed graph can be acyclic and not be a tree.

Comment: @usamec - He didn't say it was directed.